# Determine Upstream Git Changes in Jenkins using Groovy

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Our CI/CD process has multiple repositories triggering a single downstream job for testing the whole product.

I know for a current Jenkins build I can get the list of scm changes by using `currentBuild.changeSets` and then I can look at all the `items` of those changeSets to determine the commit messages, commit id etc.

However from the downstream Job standpoint upon completion of the tests run through Jenkins I want to be able to also to mention all upstream changes that have taken place.

The Jenkins test job does not allow concurrent builds. That means that multiple upstream builds might be triggering a single Jenkins test job.

I thought I could utilize Causes to determine Upstream Jobs but I don't really know how to go from there to having the changeSets.

```
    def upstreamChanges = ''

    def causes = currentBuild.rawBuild.causes

    if(causes && causes.upstreamCauses) { // upstream cause visibility
       def upstreamCauses = causes.upstreamCauses

        for (int i = 0; i < upstreamCauses.size; i++) {
            upstreamChanges += upstreamCauses[i].shortDescription
        }
    }
```

This at least gives me the Cause description but I would rather have the actual `currentBuild.changeSets` available to me.

Edit:
I basically need a way to get all upstream `Build` objects, if I have those I can use the changeSets of that build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was painful enough to figure out, might as well share the solution.

First we check all the upstream changes and add them, if nothing gets returned we attempt to get the `currentBuild.changeSets` or default to no new changes.

There is probably room for improvement here...

```
 /**
 * The max commit message length
 */
final static int MAX_COMMIT_MSG_LEN = 100

 /**
 * Build the list of Changes triggering this Jenkins build, including any upstreams Jenkins jobs <br/>
 * @param s Current build object, it's a 'this' call from the pipeline
 * @return A string with all the changes in the current and upstream build, 'no new changes' is returned if empty
 */
static buildChangeList(s) {
    def changes = ''

    Run<?, ?> cur = s.currentBuild.rawBuild
    Cause.UpstreamCause upc = cur.getCause(Cause.UpstreamCause.class)
    while (upc != null) {
        Job<?, ?> p = (Job<?, ?>) Jenkins.getActiveInstance().getItemByFullName(upc.getUpstreamProject())
        if (p == null) {
            s.echo 'There is a break in the build linkage, could not retrieve upstream build information'
            break
        }
        cur = p.getBuildByNumber(upc.getUpstreamBuild());
        if (cur == null) {
            s.echo 'There is a break in the build linkage, could not retrieve upstream build information'
            break
        }
        changes += "\nJenkins Trigger Job - $upc.upstreamProject"
        changes +=  retrieveChangeSet(cur.changeSets)

        upc = cur.getCause(Cause.UpstreamCause.class)
    }

    if (!changes) { // no upstream changes at all, see if current build has any changes
        def currentBuildChanges = retrieveChangeSet(s.currentBuild.changeSets)

        changes = currentBuildChanges ?: '\n - No new changes'  // if no current build changes, use default message
    }
    return changes
}

/**
 * Retrieve all the change sets available. Include the git author, commit message and commit id
 * @param changeSets The changeSet object from Jenkins
 * @return A string with all the changes found within the change set
 */
static retrieveChangeSet(changeSets) {
    def changes = ''

    for (int i = 0; i < changeSets.size(); i++) {   // iterate through all the available change sets
        for (int j = 0; j < changeSets[i].items.length; j++) { // iterate through all the items of a single changeset
            def entry = changeSets[i].items[j]
            def commitmsg = entry.msg.take(MAX_COMMIT_MSG_LEN)
            changes += "\n[${entry.author}] - ${commitmsg}  -  Commit ${entry.commitId}"
        }
    }
    return changes
}
```

Edit: If you are having issues running the above code it might be an import issue.

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.FilePath
import hudson.node_monitors.*
import java.time.LocalDateTime
```